# Contains with a predicate (/find/search) for a java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, queue, blockingqueue

The `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` has a convenient `contains` method:

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if this queue contains the specified element.
 * More formally, returns {@code true} if and only if this queue contains
 * at least one element {@code e} such that {@code o.equals(e)}.
 *
 * @param o object to be checked for containment in this queue
 * @return {@code true} if this queue contains the specified element
 * @throws ClassCastException if the class of the specified element
 *         is incompatible with this queue
 *         (<a href="../Collection.html#optional-restrictions">optional</a>)
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 *         (<a href="../Collection.html#optional-restrictions">optional</a>)
 */
public boolean contains(Object o);
```

My need is a bit more specific: to apply a `predicate` / search criteria. Is there any way to do this short of

```
  Using a ArrayBlockQueue
  Invoking toArray
```

That will work .. but what if the queue were large? This could cause memory allocation issues.

Comment: That seems like a good case for multiple queues instead of trying to shoehorn a queue into some strange, non-queue-ish behaviour.

Comment: @pvg  The search is based on finding a specific ID in a message. It is not the case of having "several" queues based on a fixed predicate. We would need  a queue for every message when following that approach.

Comment: If the message ids are unique all you have to do is override .equals. Or set some sort of priority. If you must identify a specific message, what is the point of using a queue which imposes an order? You should describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of 'how do I make a queue behave like not-a-queue'.

Comment: 'all you have to do is override .equals.'  The container is an anonymous tuple: it would require changing the elements of the queue to a different class. Maybe that's a reasonable approach - but it *is* different than the question.   Re: make queue act like non queue. I built custom queuing systems last decade already..  This is a queue and asking to do a search does not make it not so.

Comment: Asking it to do a search is asking for out of order access. Sure, you can add that to a queue. Or you can use another data structure to track whatever it is you want to access out of order. But you're not going to find a lot of rich support for that sort of thing in a Queue because generally, that's not the primary job of a Queue. As you can see reflected in the Queues provided by the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you **should** be doing this, but it seems like you **could** do it:

```
public static class Matcher<T> {

    Predicate<T> predicate;
    Class<T> clazz;

    public Matcher(Predicate<T> t, Class<T> clazz) {
        this.predicate = t;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && this.clazz.isInstance(o)) {
            System.out.println("Checking item " + o + " against predicate " + this.predicate);
            return this.predicate.test((T) o);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> oddsOnly = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    oddsOnly.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13));

    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> oddsAndEves = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    oddsAndEves.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

    Predicate<Integer> evenPredicate = (i) -> i % 2 == 0;
    System.out.println(oddsOnly.contains(new Matcher<>(evenPredicate, Integer.class))); // prints false

    System.out.println(oddsAndEves.contains(new Matcher<>(evenPredicate, Integer.class))); // prints true
}
```

Output:

```
Checking item 1 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 3 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 5 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 7 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 9 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 11 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 13 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
false
Checking item 1 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
Checking item 2 against predicate QueueEquals$Matcher$$Lambda$1/531885035@816f27d
true
```

It does make me want to take a shower though.... Plus, as [pvg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5087125/pvg) points out correctly - this isn't guaranteed to work. BlockingQueue implementations might call `hashCode()` before calling `equals()` and then we'd be screwed.

A saner option would be to just iterate over the blocking queue, and run the predicate against each element. The `BlockingQueue` interface doesn't have an `iterator`, but many blocking queue implementation, such as `ArrayBlockingQueue`, and `LinkedBlockingQueue` do.

Comment: That is terrifying! But also not "guaranteed" (in the pedantic sense) to work because a Collection implementation isn't guaranteed to call equals. "This specification should not be construed to imply that invoking Collection.contains with a non-null argument o will cause o.equals(e) to be invoked for any element e"

Comment: I share the sentiment. It's horrible, but it would work with implementations that don't call `hashCode` before calling equals. Anyway, I've added a saner solution to the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just stream over the `Queue` (in parallel if you'd like) and filter out your element using your predicate. `BlockingQueue` is a `Queue`, which is a `Collection` and thus defines `stream()` and `parallelStream()`. Something along the following:

```
public class SampleApplication {

    private static final int ELEMENT_COUNT = 100000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Element> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(ELEMENT_COUNT);
        List<Element> elements = Stream.generate(SampleApplication::createElement).limit(ELEMENT_COUNT).collect(Collectors.toList());
        blockingQueue.addAll(elements);

        blockingQueue.stream().filter(getFilterPredicate(5)).findAny().ifPresent(System.out::println);
        blockingQueue.stream().filter(getFilterPredicate(105)).findAny().ifPresent(System.out::println);
        blockingQueue.stream().filter(getFilterPredicate(-1)).findAny().ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Predicate<Element> getFilterPredicate(int value) {
        return e -> e.getId() == value;
    }

    private static int i = 0;
    private static Element createElement() {
        return new Element(++i);
    }

    static class Element {
        private int id;
        private String message;

        public Element(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            this.message = "Default msg";
        }

        //Getters, Setters & toString omitted
    }
}
```

Having the following output the found values:

```
Element{id=5, message=Default msg}
Element{id=105, message=Default msg}
```